# IndexError reading in comments in source code folder

Tags: python, file-io, documentation, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm writing a program to go through a list of files that I have passed in by list 'queue'.

I'm trying to go through the files line by line and select only the text either in a single-line comment, or a multi-linecomment.  ("//" and "/* */" -> Possibly on more than one line).

I'm unable to see why my program is not going to the next line when it is supposed to.  The variable 'stepper' is being incremented if the end-of-comment designation 'terminated' is not met.

I've been error testing and reworking this for a few days now and I'm not exactly sure why this isn't working.

I'm sorry for the sloppy code.

```
def main(queue):
    for item in queue:
        with open("output.txt", "a") as out_file:
            out_file.write(str("\t<FILE: " + item.split("\\")[len(item.split()) - 1] + ">"))
            java_file = list(open(item, "r"))
            for line in range(0, len(java_file)):
                for i in range(0, len(java_file[line])):
                    multi_builder = []
                    single_lines = []
                    if (java_file[line][i] == "/" and java_file[line][i + 1] == "/"):
                        single_lines.append(java_file[line][i:])
                    if (java_file[line][i] == "/" and java_file[line][i + 1] == "*"):
                        stepper = 0
                        terminated = False
                        while not terminated:
                            for char in range(0, len(java_file[line + stepper])):
                                if not java_file[line][char].strip() == "":
                                    print (java_file[line][char])
                                    if (java_file[line][char] == "*" and java_file[line][char + 1] == "/"):
                                        if stepper == 0:
                                            multi_builder.append(java_file[line][i:char + 1])
                                        multi_builder.append(java_file[line][:char + 1])
                                        terminated = True
                                    else:
                                        multi_builder.append(java_file[line])
                                        stepper += 1
```

Comment: It would help to include the stack trace in the question

Comment: It's not clear what you think the problem is here.

Comment: Also, we can probably help you find the solution to whatever your problem is, but it looks like you're reinventing the wheel here.  [Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) are designed for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're interested in an alternate approach rather than help debugging your approach, but using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) makes this task much easier:

```
import re

singleLinePattern = re.compile("//.*$", flags=re.MULTILINE+re.DOTALL)
multiLinePattern = re.compile("/\*.*?\*/", flags=re.MULTILINE+re.DOTALL)

def main(queue):
    for item in queue:
        with open("output.txt", "a") as out_file:
            out_file.write(str("\t<FILE: " + item.split("\\")[len(item.split()) - 1] + ">"))
            with open(item, "r") as f:
                java_file = f.read()
            print "singles:", singleLinePattern.findall(java_file)
            print "multis:", multiLinePattern.findall(java_file)
            # You can write the results to the output file here.
```